# Java Hibernate a conditional Criterion based on nullability of property is possible?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple query like this.

```
select id,status,c01,c02,c03 from mytable
where 
criterion1 
and criterion2 
and criterion3
```

I need to add another filter like this

```
//In Java
if(mytable.status=1){
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("anotherFilter",anotherFilterValue));
}
```

But the status value comes in the query i mean i can filter in memory but i would like to be able to filter in the DB directly

Like the ordering using case can i use some approach to make it?

Like

```
select id,status,c01,c02,c03 from mytable
where 
 criterion1 = ?
 and criterion2 = ? 
 and criterion3 = ?
 and
 case status is null 
     ? anotherFilter = :valueToFilter 
     : 1=1//IS NOT NULL NOTHING TO DO..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you.

```
select id,status,c01,c02,c03 from mytable
  where 
    criterion1 = ?
    and criterion2 = ? 
    and criterion3 = ?
    and 
       ((status is null and anotherFilter = :valueToFilter) 
       or (status is not null))
```

For criterion api

```
//In Java
criteria.add(
    Restrictions.or(
         Restrictions.isNotNull("status"),
         Restrictions.and(
           Restrictions.eq("anotherFilter",anotherFilterValue),
           Restrictions.isNull("status")
         )
    )
);
```

Comment: says cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method or(Criterion,LogicalExpression)
  location: variable criteria of type Criteria

Comment: i fixed it, simple typo.